# Visual Studio 2015 highlighting / intellisense stops working after dependency rebuilt

Tags: visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

While working on two Visual Studio solutions, one of which depends on the other, if I build the dependency the other 'master' project seems to lose track of the dependency, but only as far as intellisense and syntax highlighting.

So the master project can compile just fine but the red squigglies will tell me that any types defined in the dependency don't exist. If I close and reopen the solution (or unload and reload the project) things return to normal, until such time as I need to make a change in the dependency again.

Has anyone encountered similar issues and if so is there a solution other than having to close and reopen Visual Studio or unload and reload the project?

Comment: It's unusual to have dependencies between **solutions**. Typically you have dependencies between **projects** within one solution.

Comment: LOL OK then I'll just tell my organisation that they're doing things wrong and that all our software from actual products through to automated tests should live in one solution that 30-40 people work on simultaneously.

Comment: Unusual doesn't mean wrong. Perhaps ask one of the 30-40 other people if they've had the same issue...

Comment: And see [Microsoft's recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx) on the matter.

Comment: It's not unusual though, is it? And I've already asked other people in my organisation which is why I'm forced to endure conversations like this in the hopes of getting an answer. As for the article about setting up dependencies using Team Development with Source Safe from 2002, so far it's not helping me identify what's changed between Visual Studio 2010 and 2015 that's making this standard feature stop working.

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Just rebuild solution?

Comment: The solution builds fine. No combination of cleaning/rebuilding either the dependency or the solution in question does anything to the syntax highlighting or intellisense suggestions.

Comment: did you reference the dll or the project from the other solution (include the project to your solution)?

Comment: @Ppp yes, as I said the solution builds correctly.

Comment: @user1620220 why is it unusual to have dpendencies between solutions? Isn't the idea of a DLL to contain solutions to a general problem that can be consumed by multiple different applications?

Comment: @MichaelRibbons Yes, but if you are developing two DLLs and there is a dependency between them (like in OP's situation) it is better to load them into a single solution for the reasons outlined in the article I linked. And as OP found out VS just handles it better.

Comment: @user1620220 That's a rather long article. Can you paste the paragraph lead in for the part you are referring to?

Comment: @user1620220 Where did OP say putting everything in one solution worked for him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derf Skren!

I do not think there is a solution I cannot seem to find it I will report this to Microsoft for you and I would try unloading and reloading it as that may work.

Hopefully, that works,
Liam

Comment: Thanks Liam, as I outlined in the question, unloading and reloading does work but I still can't work out why the problem occurs and why this is broken in 2015 but not 2010.